# Importing html tables into an android app

Tags: android, sqlite, jsoup

I plan on displaying dates and times in an android application but I am stuck on how I would implement this.

My Idea:
At the beginning of every month, a new calendar is downloaded. This information is displayed within the app and no internet connection is necessary for the rest of the app usage.

The information is in the form of an html table. How can I import this table, and display it within the App (also allowing the user to view only certain information in the table (querying the table))

Do I have to import this table into an sqlite database? or is there a less complicated way of doing this. I would like to limit the number of times the user has to access the internet, therefore it would be necessary to store the html table within the app itself.

Comment: Is there a way you could get the information in a way other than HTML? Like JSON?

Answer (score 1):

How about save the table as an xml file? With the xml information you can query, or handle the data as array or list

Comment: Thank you, this sounds complicated though.

Comment: How would you go about saving an HTML table to XML?

Comment: If the docset of the document is xhml or 5, the html is already an xml. If it is 4.01, you have to put the tags and attributes in lowercase, that's it. You can also parse the document as a string and modifying it as you desire, if there are some other problems( like missing closing tag, and so on )

Answer (score 1):

Can you create a way to access your data in a more "friendly-way"? For example you could create an endpoint online where the app will send a request, download the JSON and save that in a internal database (SQLite, check [this if you don't know how](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)).

Or, the ugly way would be to parse the table in the device using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) (which you tagged). Then it's the same, you should save it in a database and read the data from there.

By the way, I would not store directly the html table, because then you will need to parse it every time you need something (p.s it will be slow)

Comment: Would it be a complicated option if I were to download the html table, and use JSON to convert it and save ti to the SQlite database, all within the application itself?

Comment: You cannot convert a HTML table using a Json parser. You need a HTML parser and then save to the SQLite database. (anyway yes, everything will happen in the device.)

Comment: May I please have some resources on this, So I am looking to convert html to JSON using an html parser. Then this will be inserted into the SQlite database correct?

Comment: If you want to convert html to json, do it on the server and expose an endpoint. It will help you in the future if you need that data in other places. Anyway, i'm not aware of any lib that does it for you, so I think you shoul do everything by yourself using an HTML parser (Jsoup, I linked the documentation in the post) and then convert it to JSON using some JSON library (search Gson on Google)